# World choroplet map

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

can you help me with the choroplet map to plot count values for several countries (from countries vector). Rest of the countries should the gray or white.

Many thanks in advance!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(see)
library(maps)

# vector of countries
countries <- c("Mexico", "USA", "Germany", "France",
               "Spain", "China", "India", "Australia")

# vector of counts ---
count_response <- c(80, 200, 180, 175, 140, 250, 230, 240)

worldMap <- map_data("world")
ggplot(data = worldMap,
       aes(x = long,
           y = lat,
           group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(colour = "black",
               fill = "gold") +
  labs(x = "Longitude",
       y = "Latitude") +
  theme_lucid()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to left join your data to the world map data frame. That will allow you to map the fill color to `count_response`:

```r
worldMap <- map_data("world")

df <- data.frame(countries, count_response)

ggplot(data = dplyr::left_join(worldMap, df, by = c(region = "countries")),
       aes(x = long,
           y = lat,
           group = group,
           fill = count_response)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Longitude",
       y = "Latitude") +
  theme_lucid(base_size = 16) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red4", high = "yellow")
```

[image]